# Unable to show updated v-model value in input

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```js
const BasicInput = {
  template: '<input v-model="content" @input="handleInput" />',
  prop: ["value"],
  data() {
    return {
      content: this.value
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.$emit("input", this.content);
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { name: "" },
  mounted() {
    self = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      self.name = "test";
    }, 2000);
  },
  components: { BasicInput }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <basic-input v-model="name"></basic-input>
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong> {{ name }}
  </p>
</div>
```

How do I get the updated v-model value to also show in the input tag ?

Comment: I got this working as expected -I think-: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPNPez. After two seconds 'test' appear both in the name and the input.  It's not clear what is the problem here.

Comment: @Sergeon Indeed. The only difference is the VueJS version - 2.5.17 vs 2.6.10. it must be it

Comment: Checked, and it actually is! Not sure what they did in 2.6 to fix this. Is upgrading to 2.6 an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `v-bind` the property for the `BasicInput` component. The short form of it is `:`.

See `<basic-input :value="name"></basic-input>` usage below, only changed it.

```js
const BasicInput = {
  template: '<input v-model="content" @input="handleInput" />',
  prop: ["value"],
  data() {
    return {
      content: this.value
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.$emit("input", this.content);
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { name: "" },
  mounted() {
    self = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      self.name = "test";
    }, 2000);
  },
  components: { BasicInput }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <basic-input :value="name"></basic-input>
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong> {{ name }}
  </p>
</div>
```